# Accessing HTML5 data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes, jquery-easyui

I'm trying to work with HTML5 data-* attributes.
However I'm using the EasyUI framework and it's being problematic.

HTML5 defines options are set as follows:
`<div data-options="{region:'north', title:'North Region', border:true}">`

But EasyUI enforces they are set like (no curly brackets):
`<div data-options="region:'north', title:'North Region', border:true">`

Is there a way to access the attribute object without writing my own parser function? If I have to I must but I figure there must be a better way.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: First Step: File a bug with EasyUI. Second step: make the attribute valid JSON so you can parse it.

Comment: Neither of those two forms are valid JSON, so yes you have to write your own parser.

Comment: You can access the custom attributes with jQuery .data() or with .attr()

Comment: @epascarello : Unfortunately this seems to be a "feature" of their framework.

Comment: @Jay : Yes, I am aware of this but my question relates to the data format not being compliant with what is expected. The standard functions cannot handle the format.

Comment: Have you tried escaping or urlencoding the value when you set `data-options`?

Comment: What's wrong with data-region="north" data-title="North region" data-border="true" or data-options-region="north" etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source, there is a method that does this.

```
$.parser.parseOptions(element);
```

Demo with just the method extracted: http://jsfiddle.net/FnJAE/

Note: this method is not documented, therefore it is subject to change without notice.

Comment: This does exactly what I want. Works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you know it will always be formatted as an object you could just:

```
jsonData = JSON.parse("{" + element + "}");
```

Comment: This won't work, even with the brackets it is still invalid json.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, you really dont have to do all that parsing. Though your HTML does need some change in quotes: [<sub>**See Reference jQuery.Data() HTML5**</sub>](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5)

> HTML

```
<div id="Bob" data-options='{"region":"north", "title":"North Region", "border":"true"}'></div>
```

> Script

```
console.log($("#Bob").data("options").title);
// Will return String "North Region"

console.log($("#Bob").data("options").region);
// Will return String "north"

console.log($("#Bob").data("options").border);
// Will return String "true"

console.log($("#Bob").data("options")
// will return a JSON Object but it is EASY to convert to Array
var eleData = $("#Bob").data("options"),
    eleArray = new Array();
for (x in eleData) { eleArray[x] = eleData[x]; }
```

Comment: I agree, fix the data to be correct json, but that isn't an option without modifying the easyui core (which wouldn't really be that difficult, tbh). http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/index.php#

Comment: I still say jQueryUI is 100x better and much more beneficial.